# How I can run functions, when I have only one name?

Tags: clojure

Example. We have very easy funcs.

```
(defn func1 []
  (println "i'm func1"))

(defn func2 []
  (println "i'm func2"))
```

And I create list with names of this functions.

```
(def listOfFunc '(func1 func2))
```

How I can run this functions, when I get name of functions from list?

Sorry for my bad english and very noob question.

Comment: (defn run [f]
  (f))

(run (first mylist))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why these functions are stored in a list?

If no, then you can use a vector which will result into something like this:

```
(def fns [func1 func2]) 
(map #(%) fns)
```

Note that this will result into a lazy seq of two nils: `(nil nil)`. If however your functions are only for side-effects, as the ones you listed, then you can wrap them into a [dorun](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dorun):

```
(dorun (map #(%) fns))
```

which will return a single `nil`.

Now, if you still prefer using a list, you will have to resolve your symbols into the corresponding functions. So I guess something like this would work:

```
(map #((ns-resolve 'foo.core %)) listOfFunc)
```

where `'foo.core` should be replaced with the namespace that has your functions.

Comment: Using a list `(list func1 func2)` or a vector `[func1 func2]` makes no difference. The problem is that *quoting* the list causes the symbols not to be resolved, which forces you to resolve them later; `'(func1 func2)` is a list of symbols, not a list of functions. There's no reason to use that here. Also, `(run! #(%) fns)` is cleaner and more efficient than `(dorun (map #(%) fns))`. Actually, if the functions have side effects (as they do in this case), you shouldn't use `map` at all, because its laziness can easily lead to bugs through unpredictable execution order.

Comment: (dorun (map #(%) fns)) may be shortened to (run! #(%) fns).